# How to get bootstrap current screen size?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I'm able to get the current viewport by using Responsive Bootstrap Toolkit but is there a way to get current screen size as well?

For example: xs (viewport), 425 (screen size)

Answer (score 1):

View this: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Sizes are noted at top of table.  Note that bootstrap codes in mobile-first.